# Compactness of $\{b^T x = 1\} \cap \{ x \geq 0\}$ in $\mathbb{R}^n$

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, convex-optimization

I'm trying to prove the Compactness of $\{b^T x = 1\} \cap \{ x \geq 0\}$ in $\mathbb{R}^n$ ( b is a fixed point in $\mathbb{R_{++}}^n $)in order to prove the existence of a function's global minimum.

The function is not coercive, so I must show the above space is compact.
But I don't see how I can prove that.

It doesn't even seem to be compact in $\mathbb{R}$.
Could anyone give me a hint?

Comment: It is closed because it is the intersection of two closed sets.

Comment: Thanks, I meant compact

Comment: It is compact **iff** all components of $b$ are non zero and have the same sign.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As all components are positive we get:
$$ b^T x \geq (\min_i{b_i})\cdot(\max_i x_i)$$
so
$$1\geq C||x||_\infty$$
for some $C>0$.

So the set is then bounded and clearly closed, so it is compact.

It is closed, as $\{x\geq0\}$ is closed (monotonity of limits) and $\{b^Tx=1\}$ is closed (linearity of limits). Intersections of closed sets are closed.

Comment: Just to elaborate, we have $b^Tx = b_1x_1 + \ldots + b_nx_n \geq (\min_i b_i)(x_1 + \ldots + x_n) \geq (\min_i b_i) (\max_i x_i)$ since $x_i \geq 0$ and $\min_i b_i >0$.

Comment: Thank you ! I don't see why you're taking $b_j <0$ though since all of its components are strictly positive?

I also don't see why $\forall c >0 , x_i = (1/b_i - cb_j)$ ?

Comment: They showed what happens when $b_j <0$ to emphasize why we require $b_i > 0$ for all $i\in\{1,\ldots,n\}$. If a single $b_j$ is less than $0$ then choosing $x_i$ as they described will result in unbounded behavior.

Comment: @frenchstudent00 Sorry, I missed that actually $b>0$ by the question, my brain somehow skipped that. And that was worded badly, it means for any $c>0$ if we define $x_i,x_j$ this we we get a problem.